# Single certificate for multiple relying party trusts

Tags: windows-server-2012, certificate, single-sign-on, adfs

I'm using ADFS 2.1 on Windows 2012 (not R2), with an SQL database.

By default it should not be possible to have multiple Relying Party Trusts with the same certificate, but an optional update should allow that (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2877424).

I have a system where the update should have been applied, but I'm getting an error (MSIS7613) that makes think it was not.

Is there a way to check if the uniqueness constraint is enforced or not?

Answer (score 1):

You should note that after the hotfix has been applied on your Federation server without any error messages, a **reboot** is required to make the changes effective.

If it still doesn't work after reboot, then you may have to request a support ticket with Microsoft CSS for further troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm actually asking for a way to verify if the constraint is present or not, not about installation instructions.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to verify this, you really should contact Microsoft for help.